# How to use a pressure sensor (transducer)?

Tags: power-supply, sensor, measurement, transducer

I have this pair of pressure sensors that are addressable transducers. I want to use them for a project but I don´t really get how to get them to work. I´m used to the type of sensor that has 3 cables( Vcc, GND, and DATA) and these ones only have two cables so I´m kinda lost. These sensors are supposed to give a certain frequency depending on the pressure applied to the sensor.

I found some data on how it's supposed to work but I don´t get what kind of circuit should I use to be able to use this data.

https://www.lancier-monitoring.de/fileadmin/media/pdf/Produkte/englisch/Tech_Info_Tx_Funktion_engl.pdf

"During the transmission, the sensor modulates the currency at a frequency that corresponds to the measured value at 3.7 mApp (= 0 dBm/600 Ω) onto the DC supply current. Therefore the used pair is power supply (direct current) and transmission media (alternate current) at the same time."

[image: Sine wavemodulation]

This is how the signal looks when transmitting data.

[image: Actual sensor]

And this is the actual sensor. Any help on how to use it would be appreciated .

Comment: Maybe it doesn't have a manufactured pin for data. I'm curious, was this pulled off a larger device?

Comment: It was originally used by a Lancier Monitoring System

Comment: It seems as though you have all the information. Could you be more specific as to what you have a hard time understanding? Hook them up to a power source between the min and max. Measure the current with something. Read the frequency of the current and get the pressure.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the device modulates the power supply by drawing current in a data pattern.  To measure this you can place a small series impedance (resistor) in series and use a differential opamp to measure it.  To remove the DC offset of the normal device current you can add a high pass filter C1 and R6.
Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs8Lts.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note: You'll need to set your gain, this is just for topology.

Or you can do the same on the ground side, and then just measure it with a single ended opamp.